# Replace Values in Vector on Specific Place in R

Tags: r, statistics, outlier

I want to make $5^{th}$,$10^{th}$,$15^{th}$,$20^{th}$ and $25^{th}$ values of vector an outlier in all xs by using `x1 [5]+OT1`,`x1 [10]+OT1` and so on. For this purpose I have made this R code,

```
n=25

x1<-runif(n,0,1)
x2<-runif(n,0,1)
x3<-runif(n,0,1)
x4<-runif(n,0,1)
x<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)

OT1<-mean(x1)+100
OT2<-mean(x2)+100
OT3<-mean(x3)+100
OT4<-mean(x4)+100
```

I have tried command `replace()` and also `modify()`, but none of them replace them at once at least in one vector. Kindly help me in this manner.

> **Edit**

by using comment of @user2974951 I tried this

```
x1[seq(5,25,5)]=x1[seq(5,25,5)]+100
Nx1<-replace(x1,x1==x1[5],x1 [5]+OT1)

x2[seq(5,25,5)]=x2[seq(5,25,5)]+100
Nx2<-replace(x2,x2==x2[5],x1 [5]+OT2)

x3[seq(5,25,5)]=x3[seq(5,25,5)]+100
Nx3<-replace(x3,x3==x3[5],x3 [5]+OT3)

x4[seq(5,25,5)]=x4[seq(5,25,5)]+100
Nx4<-replace(x4,x4==x4[5],x4 [5]+OT4)
Nx<-data.frame(Nx1,Nx2,Nx3,Nx4)
```

but its not working well

> **Results**

```
         Nx1          Nx2         Nx3          Nx4
1    0.46815292   0.08606537   0.3307899 4.362630e-01
2    0.59723633   0.12122892   0.4819987 7.753236e-01
3    0.56219881   0.25936144   0.4990369 8.125097e-03
4    0.58366209   0.90552595   0.7368288 9.701722e-01
5  201.53593455 201.43976570 201.2130687 2.014071e+02
6    0.05521220   0.61975750   0.8296397 9.942981e-02
7    0.99058967   0.59373303   0.1156678 2.632295e-01
8    0.96428154   0.41710719   0.2547667 4.605275e-01
9    0.49978441   0.98922281   0.7526796 6.978671e-01
10 100.63831600 100.24166490 100.1790951 1.009707e+02
11   0.42694764   0.67506156   0.3142930 8.022078e-02
12   0.76015772   0.93265460   0.5734483 2.417875e-01
13   0.92832414   0.95247906   0.2578651 2.536677e-01
14   0.38818813   0.47634761   0.7163780 4.091937e-01
15 100.95118175 100.35951345 100.5519005 1.007286e+02
16   0.34262275   0.42573721   0.7594048 2.707246e-01
17   0.91930401   0.33828510   0.2679736 7.299545e-01
18   0.45901144   0.95876530   0.6419959 9.764771e-01
19   0.08840004   0.34092442   0.7492228 5.148988e-01
20 100.63958996 100.25792655 100.1351512 1.007377e+02
21   0.81191203   0.88845305   0.6504586 6.138992e-01
22   0.05737578   0.27700759   0.1193294 9.060633e-01
23   0.72447661   0.41372855   0.3055600 5.396204e-01
24   0.47942584   0.71890752   0.4814340 3.924752e-01
25 100.68191347 100.11710451 100.0443692 1.002326e+02
```

Why observation $5^{th}$ is 200+ and no outlier in $x4$???

Comment: Something like `x[seq(5,25,5)]=x[seq(5,25,5)]+100`?

Comment: @user2974951 Kindly see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You have a data frame with 4 columns, each columns has 25 rows. You want to replace every 5th element with an outlying value (the mean of the column).

```
apply(x,2,function(i){
    i[seq(5,25,5)]=i[seq(5,25,5)]+mean(i)
})
```

Comment: For my further work, i have to increase my $n$ and replacement is till 25th observation, but in that replacement is done till end. How to control this?

Comment: Your code is different from mine, have you tried using my code to get the desired result? It should work. As for increasing $n$, all you have to do is change $25$ to the new value, or for ex. `nrow(x)`.

Comment: For Increasing n, suppose $n=50$ only want to change in 1st 25 values...

Comment: OK then it's the same code.

Answer (score 1):

You added 100 twice. And Nx4 is the same -- except that it's in scientific notations.

```
Nx1 = x1
Nx1[seq(5, 25, 5)] = mean(x1) + 100
```

will do.